# Provider does not support unwrapping javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor

Tags: java, hibernate, eclipselink

I am trying to implement multitenancy and I am getting this error

> Provider does not support unwrapping javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor

This is the code sample thats causing an error

```
protected EntityManager getEntityManager(String multitenancyIdentifier) throws SQLException {
    final SessionFactoryImplementor sf = emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class);
    final MultiTenantResolver tenantResolver = (MultiTenantResolver) sf.getCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver();
    tenantResolver.setTenantIdentifier(multitenancyIdentifier);
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

Comment: And your provider is? How did you get this Emf, and why are you tagging this question with EclipseLink if using Hibernate?

Comment: I was using eclipseLink and migrated to Hibernate because I  wanted to implement multitency using schema per tenant which is something I did not see on elcipseLink, and the emf is the entityManagerFactory  which is                 
 @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "PU")
    EntityManagerFactory emf;

Comment: EclipseLink has many multi tenancy options, see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/solutions/multitenancy003.htm . Schema is similar to table per tenant if you can use the same connection pool. Otherwise, could your issue be you are still using EclipseLink? You cannot unwrap an EMF from one provider to another - you'll have to specify the provider to use in your configuration and/or persistence.xml. PS the code you seem to attempt to use to get an EM doesn't seem thread safe.

Comment: I think that you are right by saying that I might be using EclipseLink which is why I actually tagged EclipseLink to this, I have never really attempted to migrate from EclipseLink before, and about the table per tenant on EclipseLink is it not on the same schema only different tables ?

Comment: Schemas are treated as just a table prefix in EclipseLink; check out the type=SCHEMA in the linked doc as a parameter to the TenantTableDiscriminator annotation.